# WAMP crashed after computer shutted down

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

Wamp doesn't work since my computer suddenly shutted down (having run Wamp), yet before that it was working fine. The system is Win7 64-bit.

I'd installed again Wamp x64, problem hadn't been solved. I did the same with Wamp x32 but problem still was current.

When I select `Apache->Service->Test Port 80`, I get  `Your port 80 is not actually used`. When it is `Apache->Service->Install service`, I get `Your port 80 is available, Install will proceed`. After restart nothing gets turn to the better.

Moreover, when I get in `Apache->Modules`, there is exclamation mark in red triangle next to 4 Apache modules: `auth_form_module`, `cache_socache_module`, `macro_module`, `proxy_wstunnel_module`. In the past, about 1 installation back, I couldn't connect to MySQL.

**Port 80 is NOT used** by Skype, IIS or whatever else - I've checked it by various methods. No firewall or antivirus hits the spot - before it was running with no problem.

Doings in `httpd.conf`, including changing port number to 8080 or 81, brings no progression.

I walked through half of internet but no solution solves the problem.
Wamp icon is still red, when i hit `localhost`, *NOT FOUND* is printed.

Comment: In the `WAMP` menu, go to `Apache >` and select `Apache error log`. Scroll to the bottom of the file and you should see an error message of why it's not starting. Maybe that can help.

Comment: `An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket` error message is put

Comment: Please add a few of the errors from the error log to your question with an edit. They are easier to read there than in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAMP wasn't working because of a virus app named YAC (Yet Another Cleaner). It's next to impossible to uninstall it, yet it's possible: one must run Windows in safe mode and then delete its directory by hand (Shift + Del).

Comment: Mark this answer as "correct" so future googlers can find it ;)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall wampserver completely, then restart your computer, then reinstall again, do following this video maybe help you

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5qkfXB2c3I
```

note: you don't need to change port 80, if it available.

Comment: I did that with both x64 and x32 - problem hasn't got off

Comment: you use latest version of wamp, and install vc++ 12

Comment: I use them vc 12 and latest wamp

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your network stack may have got corrupted try these commands from a windows terminal that you have started using the "Run as Administrator" menu option

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns

Reboot if necessary

Try WAMPServer again
```